# MSB4018 error inesperado en "XamarinTelemetry"

Tags: html, c#, android, xamarin

**Estoy creando una app en xamarin.form en Visual studio, la aplicacion se ejecutaba bien pero de pronto apareció este error**

**MSB4018   Error inesperado en la tarea "XamarinTelemetry".**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
> Nombre de archivo: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
> en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.GetFaultEventBucketFilterJson(List`1 bucketFilters)
> en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.ToString()
> en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySession.SerializeSettings()
> en Xamarin.Common.Tasks.Telemetry.GetSession(IBuildEngine4 buildEngine, String vsTelemetrySession) en D:\a_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\Telemetry.cs:línea 62
> en Xamarin.Common.Tasks.XamarinTelemetry.Execute() en D:\a_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\XamarinTelemetry.cs:línea 31
> en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

> AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
> Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
> Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
> Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> Conversor   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets 138

**Dando click al error me lleva a este codigo en el archivo: Xamarin.Sdk.targets**

```
<XamarinTelemetry Condition="$(_MobileCapability) 
                                  or $(_MauiCapability) 
                                  or $(_XamarinFormsCapability) 
                                  or $(TargetFrameworkIdentifier.StartsWith('Xamarin.'))
                                  or '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'MonoAndroid'"
                          Report="@(_TelemetryReport)"
                          TelemetrySessionId="$(VsTelemetrySession)"
                          />
    </Target>
```

He intentado editarlo pero al guardarlo me aparece esta imagen

[image: esta]

**No se como hacer que mi app se ejecute**

Comment: Ejecuta el VS con permisos de administrador. En teoría, de este modo podrás tener acceso a cualquier lado del sistema de archivos.

Comment: Gracias, eso era

Comment: Para efectos de colaboración con el sitio, lo coloqué como respuesta, cuando tengas chances la marcas como aceptada, de este modo mantenemos la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecuta el VS con permisos de administrador. En teoría, de este modo podrás tener acceso a cualquier lado del sistema de archivos.